# Why isn't Hibernate complaining about 'null' value that must be @NotNull?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-4.x

I'm having this in my `@Entity class UpcomingOffer`:

```
@Entity 
public class UpcomingOffer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull // Must not be null!
    @OneToOne
    private Store store;

    // ...
}
```

but for some reason I am able to save a `StoreOffer` without having the `Store`set:

```
    UpcomingOffer upcomingOffer = new UpcomingOffer();

    DateTime date = new DateTime(upcomingOfferDto.getDate());
    upcomingOffer.setDate(date);
    upcomingOffer.setStore(null);
```

Saving it does not cause an Exception:

```
Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
session.saveOrUpdate(upcomingOffer);
```

which causes the entry of the upcoming offer to be updated and not being associated with the `Store` that owns that `UpcomingOffer`.

Why isn't Hibernate throwing an exception here when it is annotated with `@NotNull`?

---

[image]

Comment: What version of Hibernate are you using? Since you are using the hibernate API directly I'm assuming you are not using JPA.

Comment: @greyfox I'm using `4.3.0.Final`.

Comment: This may not be it but is hibernate-validator on your class path?

Comment: @greyfox I've added a picture that shows my Hibernate dependencies for "hibernate-". It appears that there is not hibernate-validator in my classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding hibernate-validator to your classpath

If using Maven add this to your POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

If gradle add this to build.gradle

```
'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:4.3.0.Final'
```

If you are not using a dependency management / build tool, then you would have to manually download the jar and place it in your classpath

Another possible issue, maybe related, maybe not, your @OneToOne should be paired with a @JoinColumn on either the Store entity or the UpcomingOffer entity. If you are doing bidriectional mapping one of them should have the mappedBy property defined as well. If you are letting Hibernate generate the database, its possible it is not generating it as intended too.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks very much. I think I would've never thought of that. I also got `<groupId>javax.validation</groupId><artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>` included using Maven but using the hibernate-validator works now!

Answer (score 0):

@NotNull is not a JPA annotation, its a JSR 303/349 annotation (Bean Validation). As @greyfox suggested, if you add hibernate-validator to your classpath then hibernate will do validation for you because hibernate-validator is an implementation of the Bean Validation spec.

But I think that if you don't want to accept null there, then an appropriate way to go would be to mark the column as nullable by using the proper JPA annotation

```
@Column(nullable = false)
```

Note that depending on how are you generating the db tables, then you will need to also update your SQL table or not. If you are letting hibernate generate the tables for you, then hibernate will mark the column associated with the annotated field as NOT NULL for you.

Note that you can go either way (leave the validation to hibernate-validator or just enforce the validation at the DB level, or do both)... but it seems appropriate to enforce the constraint at the DB level since allowing null does not make sense for you.

Edit #1:

Ah, I missed the fact that this is a foreign-key field. So yeah, using the @OneToOne annotation as @greyfox also suggested will do the trick.